# how to subtract calculated values within a subreport in access report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I'm using Access 2016. I have a sub report as below. I want to subtract the calculated fields within this sub report.  The difference between the values of each location(Value1 of Location1 - Value1 of Location2) should be displayed in report footer. Is there any way to do this? Please help.

Location 1
      Value1    Value2     Value3

Location 2
     Value1    Value2     Value3

Answer (score 0):

Create a new report that lists these differences, add it as a subreport in the footer, and filter it on the min and max IDs of the subreports of the page.

You could also collect the differences in an array and print out this in the footer, but that will require extensive coding.

Comment: Thanks. will try it.